# Browserify Failed!: Cannot find module React

Tags: reactjs, browserify

Found an error after run the 'npm run prod' command

**[Laravel Elixir] Browserify Failed!: Cannot find module 'React' from**

My package.json file is

"dependencies": {

```
"flux": "^2.1.1",
"react": "^15.3.0",
"react-dom": "^15.3.0",
"react-tagsinput": "^3.14.0",
"remarkable": "^1.6.2",
"sweetalert": "^1.1.3"
```

}

local

**:npm version :3.6.0**

**:node version :v5.6.0**

On server

**:npm version :3.6.0**

**:node version :v5.6.0**

It works fine when I run same code on local but on server it shows browserify error.

Comment: Have you run `npm install` on the server?

Comment: I resolved the issue...
Issue was importing 'React' instead of 'react' in one of the .js file.
i correct it and it runs successfully.
but i couldn't understand how it is running successfully in local. there is also same code with import 'React'.